# How do I make the generated numbers show at once?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, joptionpane

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class p1 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int size = 50;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    while(list.size() > 0) 
    {
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: "+list.remove(index));
    }
}
}
```

When I run this program, the random numbers I generate all show up in separate message boxes, how do I change the code so it displays the array in one message box ie. The numbers you generated are: 1, 4, 5, 6, 33, etc.) Also how can I change the code so that it generates a certain amount of numbers, say 10, because it's printing out 50 as far as I can tell.

Comment: First: Create a string containing all numbers instead of directly printing them. Second: set `50` to `10` to generate only `10` numbers - simple as that.

Comment: Create a string, that will be your final result, inside your while loop append to that string the value of index(converted to string) , and after the while loop will be finished, you can just show that string in messagebox:)

Comment: Firstly I don't understand what you are trying to do. You have list with numbers from 1 to 50 (size 50) and you are trying to generate the random numbers between 1 to 50 until the list becomes empty.

Comment: the method that shows your message box should be outside the loop, and inside the loop you should construct a string in which you append to the number with a comma separator.

Comment: +1 for a nice [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Except doing this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: "+list.remove(index));
```

Put the list.remove(index) in a string variable

Then after the loop put

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: "+string variable);
```

Your mistake was just putting the dialog in the loop except outside of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int size = 10;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    String buffer = "";
    while(list.size() > 0) 
    {
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        buffer += ","+list.remove(index);

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: "+buffer);
}
```

**EDIT OF ANSWER:** One must make two variables size and range

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int size = 10;
    int range = 50;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        list.add( rand.nextInt(range));
    }


    String buffer = "";
    while(list.size() > 0) 
    {
        int index = 0;

        if(list.size() != 1)
               buffer += list.remove(index)+",";
        else if(list.size() == 1)
             buffer += list.remove(index)+",";
        index++;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: "+buffer);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, also is there anyway to add into the code a way to change the amount of numbers generated and the range in which the numbers will be generated separately, as currently "size" is responsible for both.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 50;

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (list.size() > 0) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());

            sb.append(list.remove(index) + ",");
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what is your requirement I believe.

```
Random random = new Random();

StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
for (int index = 1; index <= 50; index++) {
    buff.append(random.nextInt(50));
    if (index % 10 == 0) {
    buff.append('\n');
    } else {
    buff.append(',');
    }

}
buff.delete(buff.length() - 2, buff.length());

System.out.println(buff.toString());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selected: " + buff.toString());
```